zero dimensional quotient vector space
Let $U\subset V$ be infinite dimensional vector spaces. Consider their quotient space $V/U$ has dimension 0. Must $U=V$?
Things are clear in finite dimension- If both space have finite dimension, of course they are the same. But things is weird in infinite dimension. Since vector spaces with same cardinality of basis have same dimension, yet they might be different in nature.

Yes, there's no issue with infinite-dimensionality. By definition the quotient is $0$-dimensional iff every vector in $V$ is in $U$. The infinite-dimensional weirdness happens the other way around: it's possible for $U$ and $V$ to have the same dimension but for the quotient $V/U$ to be nonzero.

You will not find dim(V/U)=0 for infinit vector spaces. except for V/V and this does not make much sense,

I feel that you might not have asked the question that you wanted to ask. A zero-dimensional vector space over a field $k$ only has one point in it.

If $U \subset V$ then the sequence
$$
0 \to U \stackrel{j}{\to} V \stackrel{p}{\to} V / U \to 0
$$
is exact. If we assume $V / U = 0$ then $\operatorname{ker} p = V$, but because of exactness we get $\operatorname{im} j = \operatorname{ker} p = V$, so $U = V$.

I feel that phrasing this result in terms of exact sequences makes it sound a lot less trivial than it actually is.
